# How to get return value from a Cefsharp EvaluateScriptAsync

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am trying to get an array of Image in Base64 from a `CefSharp EvaluateScriptAsync`

**Code :**

```
JavascriptResponse response = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"
                                                                function foo(){
                                                                    var img = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
                                                                    var finalArray = {};
                                                                    for ( var i=0; i < img.length; i++ )
                                                                    {
                                                                        if (img[i].hasAttribute('indexvalue')){
                                                                                var c = document.createElement('canvas');
                                                                                var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
                                                                                ctx.drawImage(img[i], 10, 10);
                                                                            
                                                                                finalArray.push(c.toDataURL());
                                                                                $('canvas').remove();
                                                                              }
                                                                    }
                                                                    return finalArray;
                                                                }
                                                                    var res = foo();
                                                                ");
```

This `response.Result` gives me `CefSharp.JavascriptResponse.Result.get returned null`. So how do I get the return array from the scrip, or any simple example will do.

Comment: Your javascript most likely doesn't return a result. Start with something simple like 1 + 1

Comment: @amaitland does var res = foo(); will return any value to response.Result?

Comment: You've assigned foo() to a var, so no.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-returns-a-result for an example

Comment: Again, start with something simple. Experiment with a few things.

Comment: omg thanks, that works. i tried something simple that returns a string and without the var res = foo();

Comment: Great, you can post an answer with your updated code to benefit others.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here was the script of `EvaluateScriptAsync` where the function was assigned to `var res = foo();` and instead should be `foo();` only

**Updated Code**

```
    JavascriptResponse response = await browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(@"
                                   function foo(){
                                                  var img = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
                                                  var finalArray = [];
                                                  for ( var i=0; i < img.length; i++ )
                                                      {
                                                        if (img[i].hasAttribute('indexvalue')){
                                                           var c = document.createElement('canvas');
                                                           var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
                                                           ctx.drawImage(img[i], 10, 10);
                                                           var dataURL = c.toDataURL('image/png');
                                                           finalArray.push(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''));
                                                           $('canvas').remove();
                                                         }
                                                       }
                                                  return finalArray;
                                                 }
                                    foo();
                                                                                    ");
                //converting your response.Result into string array 
                string[] arr = ((IEnumerable)response.Result).Cast<object>()
                                 .Select(c => c.ToString())
                                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: You have the option of using a self executing function as described in http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/ what you have is also perfectly fine.